# Is there any register to set the clock frequency for UART?

Tags: microcontroller, nxp-microcontroller

I am working with UART in LPC2148 micro controller.I could not able to find any register to set the clock frequency for the UART.Is there any register to set the clock frequency?

Comment: Do you mean the frequency of the clock feeding the UART or are you asking about setting the baud rate?

Comment: i mean the clock frequency with which UART can operate?

Comment: I'm still none the wiser, sorry. Do you mean the baud rate of the communications signal or are you talking about the peripheral clock speed? Are you talking about the baud rate being set at, say, 9600 baud, or are you saying you would like to feed the peripheral itself with a clock of varying frequency?

Comment: yes.I am talking about peripheral clock speed.

Comment: The UART, like all the peripherals, is supplied by PCLK. If you change it for one, you change it for all peripherals. However, these UARTs' baud rate generators have fractional dividers, so I am not really sure why you'd been to change PCLK?

Comment: if the peripheral clock does not have a speed limit in the vendor documentation then it can run the full speed of the system clock range, so if the main clock can do 40MHz and the PCLK can be a divide by 1 of that then the uart/timers/etc can run at 40MHz.

Comment: this does not at all mean that the IO pads can run at that speed if the uart allows a divide by 1 for the baud rate divisor.  The vendor may or may not spec the IO pad speed limit

Comment: and yes there are registers to set the main clock, registers to set the pclk divisor and ones to set the baud rate divisor.

Answer (score 0):

The "quick and dirty" method described in the reference is:

U0DLL = PCLK in Hertz / ( 16 * desired_baud_rate )

This is a simplified equation; the others have adjustments that can be made by adjusting various registers to fine-tune the serial baud rate.

From the same reference:

Now , as seen in Ex. 2 – in order to get 9600(9605 actually) bauds at 60Mhz PCLK we must use the following settings for baud generation :

U0DLL = 110 ; U0DLM = 1 ; MULVAL = 15 ; DIVADDVAL = 0
(You can convert these values to Hex =or= direclty use it in decimal form)
Now , lets make a function named “InitUART0()” which will configure and initialize UART0 as required :

```
void InitUART0(void)
{
  PINSEL0 = 0x5;  /* Select TxD for P0.0 and RxD for P0.1 */ 
  U0LCR = 3 | (1<<7) ; /* 8 bits, no Parity, 1 Stop bit | DLAB set to 1  */
  U0DLL = 110;
  U0DLM = 1;    
  U0FDR = (MULVAL<<4) | DIVADDVAL; /* MULVAL=15(bits - 7:4) , DIVADDVAL=0(bits - 3:0)  */
  U0LCR &= 0x0F; // Set DLAB=0 to lock MULVAL and DIVADDVAL
  //BaudRate is now ~9600 and we are ready for UART communication!

 }
```